# How to access an instance variable in another Ruby class?

Tags: ruby, instance, instance-variables

```
class Player

  attr_accessor :card_pile
  def initialize
    @bust = false
    @card_pile = []
  end

  def bust?
    return @cards.inject(:+) > 21
  end

end
```

I have this Player class and have initazlied card_pile variable

```
class Game

  def initialize
    @players = []
  end

  def playing_game
    puts "How many players are playing? "
    players_amount = gets.chomp.to_i
      (0...players_amount).each do
        puts ("What is the players name? ")
        name = gets.chomp
        @players.push(name)
      end
      puts @players
      player = Player.new
      player.initialize
        while @card_pile.length < 2 do
          new_card = Card.new
          @card_pile.push(new_card.value)
        end
  end
```

I wish to use this variable in the while loop below. Why cannot this be accessed in the way I am hoping it will be?

The error message is: ``playing_game': private method `initialize' called for #<Player:0x007fda53073f48 @bust=false, @card_pile=[]> (NoMethodError)`

Comment: why can i not set `attr_accessor :@card_pile` ?

Comment: not `attr_accessor :@card_pile` but `attr_accessor :card_pile`

Comment: Your question is unclear. In the title and in the text, you ask about instance variables, but the error message is about calling a private method, which is completely unrelated. So, what are you asking about: calling private methods or instance variables? Then, in the comments, you ask about accessor methods. Again, unrelated to the error message.

Comment: See "Classes, Objects, and Variables" in http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/

Answer (score 1):

`initialize` is called automatically when you make a new instance of a class using `Player.new`. You don't currently have any arguments being passed in to your initialize method, but you have set the instance variable `card_pile` with `attr_accessor`, so you can do this:

```
player = Player.new
while player.card_pile.length < 2 do
    new_card = Card.new
    player.card_pile.push(new_card.value)
end
```

Comment: ok cheers. is this not possible? why can i not set attr_accessor :@card_pile ?

Comment: Classes encapsulate their instance variables, it's one of the organizational benefits they provide. The @ symbol is just used to access instance variables within the class they are defined.